# Batteries for 3v gearbox

Tags: batteries, dc-motor

What kind of battery can I use to power a 3v DC gearbox, which can provide power for a longer duration? I have used AA batteries but they get depleted very fast. This is for a mechanical walking robot which uses a Tamiya gearbox.Thanks.

Comment: How about using "D" cells with the appropriate battery holder? Depending upon current consumption, you will get anywhere from 10 times to 20 times the life of "AA" cells.

Comment: Dwayne is correct, but to extend the concept a bit, the common off-the-shelf batteries from the drug store are all the same voltage, you can interchange them at will so long as the voltages are the same.  The difference is in the amount of Amp-hours each contains.  You can find that on the packaging or on google.

Comment: The Tamiya motors are notoriously high drain - you can use D cells, but they won't be 10 times better than AA's - maybe more like 5 times.  Some people change out the motors in the gearboxs for higher voltage ones, and then use an AA pack with more cells  in it - this higher voltage, lower current setup works better with cheap semiconductor H-bridges, too.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I haven't been able to find a similar size motor to replace the Tamiya one (unless I cut off the motor housing which would allow a slightly bigger size motor to fit on the gearbox). So will have to just try the D cells and see.

Comment: Why not just parallel several series-pairs of AA batteries? Seems quite the 'Occam's Razor acceptable" approach.

Comment: Would using the D cells spoil the motor , even though the voltage is same, the current is higher?

Answer (score 1):

1. You need to measure the current drawn by your load. Insert a multimeter on A (amps) range in series with the battery circuit somehow. Start the robot and measure the current drawn.
2. You can then compare the Ah (ampere-hour) specifications of various batteries and get an estimate of run time by dividing Ah by the multimeter amps reading. \$ Run~hours = \frac {battery~Ah}{multimeter~A} \$. Note that Ah rating is usually at a specified current draw. If you increase the current the batteries will give less Ah due to power lost as heat in the battery cells.